# Veracode pointing out vulnerabilities in Angular 15 when using innerHTML with DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, veracode

I have the following code in Angular 15, where we print an HTML response coming from an API:

**HTML:**

```
 <div [innerHTML]="htmlResponse | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

**Veracode vulnerability**

```
Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)
```

What can we do to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes. you can use this in your component, which is outputting the html. 

In HTML:
 `<div [innerHTML]="htmlResponse | safe: 'html'"></div>`

But in component, use:

`this.htmlResponse = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
            dataYouWantToSanitize
          );`

Comment: And in safe pipe implementation, use this:

`case 'html':
        value = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);`